# How can I get current category id of Virtue Mart

Tags: virtuemart

I want to change the default Featured Products module of Virtue Mart. I would like to this module show just the current category's featured product. So I need to get the current category id.

How can I get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JRequest::getInt(category_id);
```

Comment: @user594297 - Accept your answer

Answer (score 4):

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

// should be article, categories, featured, blog...

```
$view = $input->get('view');
```

// if it's a category view, this will be the category id, else the article id

```
$id = $input->getInt('id');
```

// in an article view, this will be the cat id.

```
$catid = $input->getInt('catid');
```

// this is the menu item id i.e. what you call page id I guess.

```
$Itemid = $input->getInt('Itemid');
```

I hope this will help you.. :)